# How to use a color map and have a specific color for a certain value on a stacked bar using matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, colors, colormap

I'm creating a stacked bar chart to show frequencies of different 'events' at different 'positions' [each position is a bar, and it is split by the events that occur there]. Each of the events I want to have a unique color and be distinguishable, so I'd like to use the rainbow colormap. However the final event I would like to be a white color.

So far I only have my code for the plot using rainbow, which leaves the last event as being red. How can I make it white instead?

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib as plt
from matplotlib import cm
import numpy as np

r = [0,1,2,3]
raw_data = {'1': [20, 5, 3, 2], '2': [5, 15, 5, 4],'3': [3, 5, 13, 17], '4': [2, 3, 7, 5], '5':[5, 7, 7, 7]}
df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data)
event_colours = plt.cm.rainbow(np.linspace(0, 1, 5))
sbc = df.plot.bar(stacked = True, color = event_colours)
sbc.set(xlabel="Position", ylabel="Frequency")
sbc.legend(loc='center right', bbox_to_anchor=(-0.2, 0.5))
```

Comment: How do you plan to see white bar on white background?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the last color to white, e.g. via `event_colours[-1] = (1,1,1,1)`.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

r = [0,1,2,3]
raw_data = {'1': [20, 5, 3, 2], '2': [5, 15, 5, 4],'3': [3, 5, 13, 17], 
            '4': [2, 3, 7, 5], '5':[5, 7, 7, 7]}
df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data)
event_colours = plt.cm.rainbow(np.linspace(0, 1, 5))
event_colours[-1] = (1,1,1,1)

ax = df.plot.bar(stacked = True, color = event_colours, edgecolor="k")
ax.set(xlabel="Position", ylabel="Frequency")
ax.legend(loc='center right', bbox_to_anchor=(-0.2, 0.5))
ax.figure.subplots_adjust(left=0.3)


plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to simply change the color of the top most bars by accessing them using `patches`. Then, update the corresponding legend entry. Another possible solution would be to create a custom color map.

Since white bar on white background won't be visible, I have chosen `lightgrey` color to demonstrate my solution.

```
# Your 4 import commands here
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches

# Your code goes here
# ............

# Change the color of the last 4 bars
for patch in list(sbc.axes.patches)[-4:]:
    patch.set_facecolor('lightgrey')

# Update the legend entry
hans, labs = sbc.get_legend_handles_labels() # Get the existing legends
last_bar = mpatches.Patch(color='lightgrey', label='5')
del labs[-1], hans[-1] # Delete the last red legend entry

hans.append(last_bar) # add the grey bar to the legend
sbc.legend(handles=hans, loc=2, bbox_to_anchor=(-0.3, 0.7))
```

[image]